How can I remove the "Window", "Edit" and "Help" buttons from a desktop app?
I created a new dioxus desktop app using the template created from the dx CLI, and can't seem to get rid of the Window buttons at the top of the app. I've sifted through all the methods available for window creation, and none of them remove the Window, Edit and Help buttons shown in the picture below.
Here is my app launch code:
use dioxus::prelude::*;
use tracing::Level;
use dioxus_desktop::Config;
use dioxus_desktop::tao::dpi::LogicalSize;
use dioxus_desktop::tao::window::WindowBuilder;

fn main() {
    // Init logger
    dioxus_logger::init(Level::INFO).expect("failed to init logger");

    // Create the WindowBuilder that app launches with
    let window = WindowBuilder::new()
        .with_title("Dioxus App")
        .with_inner_size(LogicalSize::new(518.0, 864.0)) // Set the window size to RPI screen ratio
        .with_decorations(false); // make window borderless

    // Create the Config with the custom window builder
    let cfg = Config::new()
        .with_custom_head(r#"<link rel="stylesheet" href="tailwind.css">"#.to_string())
        .with_window(window);

    // Launch app from cfg
    LaunchBuilder::desktop().with_cfg(cfg).launch(App);
}

And an example of the window:


@DanielA.White Not particularly, I understand I need to disable the menu but looking through Dioxus' WindowBuilder doesn't have anything to do that. I also saw in one of the comments of window.rs from Dioxus which says that "The dock and the menu bar are always disabled in fullscreen mode", but when I set fullscreen instead of a logical size I still have the menu bar.
